# How to unreverse this method in java?

Tags: java

I wrote some code:

```java
public class digitShow {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(digitShow(98198187));
    }

    public static int digitShow(int num) {
        if (num != 0) {
            System.out.print(num % 10);
            return digitShow(num / 10);
        } else
            return num;
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly fine, but I am trying to make it so instead of printing the numbers in reverse order one by one, the output rather would display each digit one by one in the order that they are entered in the parameter.

So in this case:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I've been trying to un-reverse it, but I've had no luck.

Comment: Do not print individual digits until you finished with the entire number. You can use array to store results.

Comment: Use a String. Instead of printing it `System.out.print(num%10);`, simply add to the start of the string: `myString = (num%10) + myString;`, and in the very end, print the string.

Comment: Try moving the print statement to after your recursive call, and see how that changes the output.

Comment: `System.out.println(98198187)` would also work I presume :P

Answer (score 1):

Ok, some people on comments are suggesting using arrays or similar. This is correct, however this seems like a question made by someone who is learning recursion (and, as a teacher, I can smell a homework question here).

I will not post the answer because I'd be doing your homework for you and we need good programmers in this world. If I (or anyone else) do your homework you'll never understand the basic concepts of programming, and never becoming a good programmer.

Now, building on top of smac89's comment:

Your code to reverse has an issue: it prints 0 after it reverses the digits. Why? because you are returning an integer and then printing it in your main function but you are not really using the return value anywhere else.

Try calling your method without the `System.out.println` in `main` and see what happens.

So, basically, evaluate if you really need to return an integer and, if you don't, you can now evaluate how you are calling the recursion (again, read smac89's comment).

I wish you the best in your studies!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the number by successive divisions first.  Then process the values as they are unwound from the stack.  This will print the most significant to least significant digit.  Then return the starting number.

```
public static int digitShow(int num) {
    if (num > 10) {
        digitShow(num/10);
    }
    System.out.println(num%10);  
    return num; // returns the starting number.
}
```

prints

```
9
8
1
9
8
1
8
7
98198187
```